# How to attach gnu screen without knowing tty number

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

After starting multiple gnu screen sessions with

```
screen -S name1
screen -S name2
```

I would like to selectively attach to them. If I do

```
screen -D -R name1
```

it will not attach but instead print:

```
There are several suitable screens on:
    6799.name1        (08.02.2013 15:47:23)   (Detached)
    3661.name2        (08.02.2013 13:43:25)   (Detached)
Type "screen [-d] -r [pid.]tty.host" to resume one of them.
```

It works obviously if I type:

```
screen -D -R 6799.name1
```

But I would like to attach without knowing the tty number, because I want to start the screen sessions by a script which takes the name as argument. Not knowing the tty number at this time I would need to copy by hand this number whenever I want to reattach later.

An obvious solution would be to extract the tty number from the above screen output using string operations. But that seems a little awkward. Is there a way to tell screen to attach to a specific named session, whatever the tty number is?

Note that I tried the different `[-d|-D] [-r|-R]` combinations mentioned in the man pages.

---

Note added:

I create the separate screen sessions in a script using ssh with

```
ssh -t ${host} "
    screen -S \"$exefile\" -t \"$exefile\" -R "nice -n$prio \"$exefile\" ${exeparams[@]}"; 
    exit 0";
```

Later I try to connect using

```
ssh -t ${host} "
    screen -D -R -S \"$exefile\" && 
    echo \"finished.\"; 
    exit";
```

where `$exefile` is the name of the executable and the screen session I want to connect to.

Comment: I actually went for the awkward solution when I wrote a wrapper shell script around screen https://github.com/frostschutz/Screen-Manager - it has a sm_pidof() function that extracts the number for a given name. But it also needs that for other check (such as is the screen already running or what).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reliable solution I found was the brute force method outlined in the question. To connect to an existing screen with name `$exefile` on remote `$host` via ssh, or to create a new one if it does not exist, one may use (in a bash shell):

```
ssh -t $host "
    echo \"done.\" &&
    echo \"itentifying screen ...\" &&
    myscreen=\`screen -list | sed -n \"s/^\\s*\\s\\([0-9]*\\.$exefile\\)\\s\\s*.*$/\\1/p\"\` &&
    if [ "X\$myscreen" = "X" ]; then 
        echo \"no existing screen session found, creating new\"; 
        screen -S \"$exefile\"; 
    else 
        echo \"connecting to screen \$myscreen\"; 
        screen -d -r \"\$myscreen\"; 
    fi &&
    echo \"finished.\";
    exit";
```

The first run will create a new session on `$host`. If the screen is detached with `Ctrl+a,d` the ssh login shell closes. If the same command is issued again it will reconnect to the existing screen. Multiple screen sessions with different names `$exefile` are possible and can be reattached independently. The magic is done by `sed` which searches the output of `screen -list` for a name matching the pattern `[tty].name`. Note that the screen name might need to be escaped if it contains `sed` special characters.

Answer (score 4):

Because I am the only one connecting to my `screen` sessions, and sometimes I want more than one console connected (a la multi display mode) to a session at a time, I use the `-x` switch.

```
# screen -S hosts
# screen -ls
  There is a screen on:
      12828.hosts     (Detached)
  1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-uther.
# screen -x hosts
```

From `man 1 screen`

```
   -x   Attach  to a not detached screen session. 
       (Multi display mode).Screen refuses to attach 
       from within itself.  But when cascading multiple 
       screens, loops are  not  detected; take care.
```

Comment: This could be a solution, but usually there is too much output on my screen sessions for this to be practicable.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
screen -S name1 -D -R
```

Comment: Seems I accepted this answer too early. It worked at first, but it seems to depend on the tty numbers. Now it does not work, independently of whether the screen sessions are attached, detached etc.

Comment: @highsciguy, what do you mean by _it seems to depend on the tty numbers_? I can't seem to be able to make in _not_ work. Can you please tell how to reproduce?

Comment: Please see my comment on how I create the screen sessions. I am not sure what causes the problems but it seems to work only sometimes.

Comment: @highsciguy, in which way does it not work? Does it fail to attach the session, fail to detach from the other terminal? Attach the wrong session? Does it report an error? What version of `screen` (I'm testing with the `4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704` package from Debian)

Comment: It will print a message of the sort mentioned above "There are several suitable screens on: ...". Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06 (current Ubuntu).

Comment: @highsciguy. And are you sure there aren't two screen sessions with the same session name (like `1234.vim` and `2345.vim`)?